# Change pytest rootdir

Tags: import, pytest

I am stuck with this incredibly silly error. I am trying to run pytest on a Raspberry Pi using bluepy.

```
pi@pi:~/bluepy/bluepy $ pytest test_asdf.py
============================= test session starts       ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/pi/bluepy, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
 ______________ ERROR collecting bluepy/test_bluetoothutility.py _______________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/pi/bluepy/bluepy/test_asdf.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_asdf:4: in <module>
    from asdf import AsDf
asdf.py:2: in <module>
    from bluepy.btle import *
E       ImportError: No module named btle
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.65 seconds ============================
```

I realised that my problem could be that rootdir is showing incorrect path. It should be

```
/home/pi/bluepy/bluepy
```

I've been reading [pytest docs](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html) but I just do not get it how to change the rootdir.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could just sketch up a very simple directory structure like I've done below, so that folks know where the files are at relative to one another. In addition, it will be important to know whether the directories are recognized as packages (this just means they all have an `__init__.py` file in them), since import statements can only be performed on modules in packages and subpackages (i.e., nested packages).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your problem is nothing to do with Pytest's rootdir.

The rootdir in Pytest has no connection to [how test package names are constructed](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-package-name) and rootdir is not added to `sys.path`, as you can see from the problem you were experiencing. (Beware: the directory that is considered rootdir may be added to the path for other reasons, such as it also being the current working directory when you run `python -m pytest`.)

The problem here, as others have described, is that the top-level `bluepy/` is not in `sys.path`. The easiest way to handle this if you just want to get something running interactively for yourself is as per [Cecil Curry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46903977/107294): `cd` to the top-level `bluepy` and run Pytest as `python -m pytest bluepy/test_asdf.py` (or just `python -m pytest` if you want it to discover all `test_*` files in or under the current directory and run them). But I think you will need to use `python -m pytest`, not just `pytest`, in order to make sure that the current working directory is in the path.

If you're looking to set up a test framework that others can easily run without mysterious failures like this, you'll want to set up a test script that sets the current working directory or `PYTHONPATH` or whatever appropriately. Or use [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Or just make this a Python package using standard tools that can run the tests for you. (All that goes way beyond the scope of this question.)

By the way, I concur with Cecil's opinion of [Mackie Messer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003192/107294); messing around with `conftest.py` like that is overly difficult and fragile; there are better solutions for almost any circumstance.

**Appendix: Use of rootdir**

There are only two things, as far as I'm aware, for which rootdir is used:

1. The `.pytest_cache/` directory is stored in the rootdir unless otherwise specified (with the [`cache_dir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-cache_dir) configuration option).
2. If rootdir contains a `conftest.py`, it will [always be loaded](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/lang/python/test/pytest-config.md#conftestpy), even if no test files are loaded from in or under the rootdir.

The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#initialization-determining-rootdir-and-inifile) claims that the rootdir also used to generate nodeids, but adding a `conftest.py` containing

```
def pytest_runtest_logstart(nodeid, location):
    print("logstart nodeid={} location={}".format(nodeid, location))
```

and running `pytest --rootdir=/somewhere/way/outside/the/tree` shows that to be incorrect (though node *locations* are relative to the rootdir).

Comment: "If rootdir contains a conftest.py, it will always be loaded, even if no test files are loaded from in or under the rootdir. " a caveat - it seems to be the case that the presence of conftest.py is *changing* what rootdir is. If it does not exist my pytest is using $PWD as the path.

Answer (score 15):

My first guess would be that you don't have that directory in the python path. You can add it to the python path dynamically. One simple way to do this is in a test configuration file `conftest.py`, which I believe is always executed before test discovery and test running.

For example, you might have a project setup like:

```
root
+-- tests
|   +-- conftest.py
|   +-- tests_asdf.py
+-- bluepy (or main project dir)
|   +-- miscellaneous modules
```

In which case, you could add the root dir to your python path in the `conftest.py` file like so:

```py
#
# conftest.py
import sys
from os.path import dirname as d
from os.path import abspath, join
root_dir = d(d(abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(root_dir)
```

Let me know if that's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `py.test` *is* correctly discovering the `rootdir` for your project to be `/home/pi/bluepy`. That's good.

Tragically, you are erroneously attempting to run `py.test` within your project's package subdirectory (i.e., `/home/pi/bluepy/bluepy`) rather than within your project's `rootdir` (i.e., `/home/pi/bluepy`). That's bad.

Let's break this down a little. From within the:

- `/home/pi/bluepy` directory, there is a `bluepy.btle` submodule. **(*Good.*)**
- `/home/pi/bluepy/bluepy` subdirectory, there is *no* `bluepy.btle` submodule. **(*Bad.*)** Unless you awkwardly attempt to manually inject the parent directory of this subdirectory (i.e., `/home/pi/bluepy`) onto `sys.path` as [Makie Messer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3022254/mackie-messer]) perhaps [inadvisably advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003192/2809027), Python has no means of inferring that the package `bluepy` actually refers to the current directory coincidentally also named `bluepy`. To avoid ambiguity issues of this sort, Python is typically only run *outside* rather than *inside* of a project's package subdirectory.

Since you ran `py.test` from the latter rather than the former directory, Python is unable to find the `bluepy.btle` submodule on the current `sys.path`. For this and similar reasons, `py.test` should typically *only* ever be run from your project's top-level `rootdir` (i.e., `/home/pi/bluepy`):

`pi@pi:~/ $ cd ~/bluepy
pi@pi:~/bluepy $ py.test bluepy/test_asdf.py`

Lastly, note that it's typically preferable to defer test discovery to `py.test`. Rather than explicitly listing all test script filenames on the command line, consider instead letting `py.test` implicitly find and run all tests containing some substring via the `-k` option. For example, to run all tests whose function names are prefixed by `test_asdf` (regardless of the test script they reside in):

`pi@pi:~/ $ cd ~/bluepy
pi@pi:~/bluepy $ py.test -k test_asdf .`

The suffixing `.` is optional, but often useful. It instructs `py.test` to set its `rootdir` property to the current directory (i.e., `/home/pi/bluepy`). `py.test` is *usually* capable of finding your project's `rootdir` and setting this property on its own, but it can't hurt to specify it manually. (Especially as you're having... *issues.*)

For further details on `rootdir` discovery, see [*Initialization: determining rootdir and inifile*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html) in the [official `py.test` documentation](https://docs.pytest.org).

Comment: Perhaps this is overly pedantic, but `pytest .` does not directly instruct pytest to set the rootdir to `.`; in fact it has no effect on the rootdir because the current working directory already is used in the calculation regardless of whether `.` is explicitly specified or not. (The rootdir will still be `.` even if you run `pytest subdir/`.) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170600/107294) for more details on what rootdir is really about.

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of pytest you can set the `pythonpath` setting in your pytest config, which forces pytest to add these directories onto the root.  Here's an example of how to set it in pyproject.toml

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
    '--strict-config',
    '-ra',
]
pythonpath = [
    'src/lambdas',
    'src/lambdas/data_gen',
]
testpaths = ['src/lambdas/tests']
```