# Pytest set default path/directory/fodler as project directory (solve FileNotFoundError)

Tags: pytest

I have the next tree:

```
root_project/
├── app
│   ├── default_photo_profile.jpg
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __main__.py  # My app are python package, I'm runnig it via "python -m"
│   └── ...
├── tests
│   ├── test_unit.py  # import config.py inside
│   ├── functional  # import config.py inside
│   ├── pytest.ini
│   └── ...
...
```

Currently `default_photo_profile` causing error because `tests` doesn't have this file.

Reading file in `config.py`:

```
DEFAULT_PHOTO_FILE_PATH = Path('default_photo.jpg')
with open(file=DEFAULT_PHOTO_FILE_PATH, mode='rb') as file_obj:
    DEFAULT_PHOTO_BYTES = file_obj.read()
```

**How I can solve this?**

**I tried**:

1. Patch access to `default_photo.jpg` with fixture - not helped, error during import stage, not executiion.
2. set flag to pytest comamnd line: `--rootdir app` - not helped (don't know why).
3. `try/except` for reading the file in `app.config.py` - may help but it's not my intention, I really want raise error if file not found
4. Put `default_photo.jpg` inside EVERY test directory - will help bit dirty.
5. Patch `os.path` like suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003192/11277611 - dirty
6. Include tests into package (move `__main__.py` into `root_project` - not sure that it's a good idea (have not enough experience to decide).
7. Set absolut path to `default_photo.jpg` - will fail on the production server.

**Probably adoptable solutions (What I want):**

1. Set root dir to `root_project.app` somehow inside `pytest.ini` to immitate regular execution.
2. Set root dir to `root_project.tests` somehow to place file in root of tests and access from any of `tests` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code in `config.py`:

```py
DEFAULT_PHOTO_FILE_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / 'default_photo.jpg'
with open(file=DEFAULT_PHOTO_FILE_PATH, mode='rb') as file_obj:
    DEFAULT_PHOTO_BYTES = file_obj.read()
```

Is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No! It will not help if I will run tests from non root directory, i.e. `python -m pytest /tests/functional/users/foo`

Comment: Did you check it? `Path(__file__)` is independent from workdir. I have tried `pytest D:\repos\stackoverflow\tests\functional\users\foo` which contains test that is using `from app.config import DEFAULT_PHOTO_BYTES` (config is in D:\repos\stackoverflow\app\config.py)